# Определить неиспользуемые индексы в mysql

Tags: mysql

В проекте есть таблица, в которой разработчики однажды создали много индексов. Явно, по незнанию. Сейчас это тормозит работу базы.

Удалять все индексы страшно. Во первых, из за размера таблицы удаление и добавление индекса занимает значительное время. Во вторых, сайт под нагрузкой и удаление "нужного" индекса может вызвать серьёзные проблемы.

Быть может есть какой-то способ мониторинга использования индекса? Было бы полезно знать, как часто селекты обращаются к индексу. В идеале, какие запросы используют индекс.

Comment: "какие запросы используют индекс" вам покажет `explain select...`. Если куча лишних индексов, значит можно посоветовать сделать только одно: удаляете все индексы (оставляете только PK), анализируете все запросы и добавляете те индексы, которые вы бы хотели добавить. Если сомневаетесь - значит не добавляете, без всяких сомнений. Когда получится минимальный набор действительно нужных индексов, тогда уже смотрите по тестам как ведут себя запросы. Возможно, придется добавить еще парочку индексов. Затем закрываете доступ к базе для всех на "техобслуживание", обновляете индексы и открываете доступ

Comment: "какие запросы используют индекс" а не какие индексы использует запрос. Explain тут не поможет. Проблемы подхода с "удалить все индексы" я уже описал. Проанализировать все запросы возможности нет. Т.к разные бэкэнды используют базу. Согласен, можно включить лог, потом как-то сгруппировать и отследить каждый запрос. Но это уже другой подход.

Comment: берете ваши запросы, которые выполняются часто или должны выполняться быстро и для них делаете explain, тогда и увидите какие индексы используются. Т.е. вам надо самим проделать эту работу. Ее в любом случае придется проводить, когда будете искать какие индексы стоит добавлять. А чтобы не было "проблем" из-за удаления всех индексов - и вводите "техобслуживание", как вариант - просто доступ в режиме readonly, на запасной базе выполняете все операции с индексами, а потом заливаете дамп в рабочую базу. У того же SO периодически случаются такие "режимы чтения". Вы же не для ракет ПО пишите? )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сам нашел ответ. В [этой](http://ruhighload.com/post/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85+%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2+%D0%B2+MySQL_20160616) статье.

> Самый простой способ избавления от лишних индексов — утилита [check-unused-keys](https://www.percona.com/blog/2009/06/26/check-unused-keys-a-tool-to-interact-with-index_statistics/).